# Мин сколько точек доступов необходимо для работы RSSI Fingerprinting?

Tags: fingerprint

Может метод позиционирования RSSI Fingerprinting работать с одной точкой доступа    и нужно ли знать местоположение точек доступов ?

Comment: Может и с одной, правда будет известно только, что клиент "где то в радиусе действия", а где конкретно установить нельзя. И да, разумеется координаты точек доступа должны быть известны, иначе от чего вы отсчет будете вести. Для "точной" триангуляции необходимо минимум 3 точки

Comment: 3 - мало, смотря для какой площади конечно..